# create remote queue manager in Websphere MQ

Tags: websphere, messaging, ibm-mq

I have been working with WebSphere MQ since last few days. I have only tested this with creating local queue managers and sending/receiving messages from queues that works fine as expected.

but I am not able to create remote queue manager. I am using WebSphere 8.0 for windows.

This is what I have tried in websphere explorer:

1) QueueManagers --> Add Remote Queue Managers --> Queue name

2) provide details like :

host(remote):localhost
port: 1424
server connection channel : SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN

3) next next and finish.

It gives me error as :Could not establish a connection to the queue manager - reason 2538.
 (AMQ4059)

any pointer on this why I am getting this error will be really appreciated.

thanks
Yashu

Answer (score 1):

Remote queue manager is a queue manager running on a remote host (ie another machine than your localhost).  Create a queue manager is another machine abc and connect it through the MQ Explorer.

I suggest reading this primer to understand MQ and its features http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp0021.pdf

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, i have tried giving remote host also insead of localhost then also I am getting same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

MQ Security!  You are trying to use a SYSTEM channel and the CHLAUTH is blocking you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for pointing it out. Can you please tell me how I should resolve it? by changing channel name to what?

Comment: Either create a CHLAUTH rule to allow you to connect or create another channel (i.e. TEST.CHL) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your point

```
but I am not able to create remote queue manager.
```

I am guessing you are attempting to create a queue manager on a remote machine using `Add Remote Queue Managers` menu.

The `Add Remote Queue Managers` menu in MQExplorer is for Connecting to and Administering an already existing queue manager on a remote machine. This menu does not create a queue manager on a remote machine. You must first create the queue manager on the remote machine and then connect to using `Add Remote Queue Managers` menu.

Also make sure you create `SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN` channel on the remote queue manager because this channel is not created by default.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, so it means that WebSphere MQ should be running in remote server too?? My main purpose was to send message from public cloud say OpenShift to the WebSphere running at my local machine, thats why I tried creating queue namager having remote address of OpenShift so that client hosted in OPenSHirft can connect to the MQ. Any pointer on this will be really helpful for me , Thanks a lot ~Yash